# Why do we read VaYechal on Taanis Esther?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Taanis Esther is the day when Esthers fast (or else it would be Taanis Mordechai). Why do we read Vayechal on this day?

All days are celebrated in the same way they were first celebrated.

1. Pesach - we eat Maztas the same way we did the first time.
2. Shavuos - we eat Cheesecake just like we did the first time
3. Tisha BeAv/17 Tammuz/10 Teves - we fast just like Jews did inside the walls of Jerusalem.

When you can't eat, you might as well declare a fast and read from the Torah. However, when only Esthers fast, they can't read from the Torah (since they're women).

Since we're trying to recreate the original fast when only women fasted and no one read from the Torah, why do we read from the Torah and specifically Veyechal?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 3):

The original reason why women can't read from the Torah is because it's not Kavod Tzibbur for women to do public Torah reading. Nowadays, we have [plenty](http://www.wikipedia.org/Beis_Yaakov) of women reading from the Torah in public so it lost it's lack of Kavod Hatzibbur.

So why can't women read from the Torah nowadays?

It's a Shavua (kind of like the fact that even though the Cherem of Rabbeinu Gershon expired, the Jewish people accepted a Shevua not to marry multiple wives). This is such a powerful Shevua, since even Hashem kavyachol took part in it (like the Cherem that the brothers took not to reveal Yosef's sale, in which Hashem took part).

On Erev Purim, we have a risk that feminists will demand us to undo this oath (in honor of Esther, who broke all Persian and Jewish protocol (kol kvuda bas melech pnima) to talk to Achashveirosh and Haman (both men) to save the Jews.

To avoid giving in to them, we read Vayechal, which the Gemara explains in the 5th chapter of Brachos symbolizes Moshe Rabbeinu saying that Hashem annulling his oath is "secular" and sacrilegious.

Therefore, we're just sending a message to people in the Viber Shul - Don't count on it!!

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer.

The word חל means "sick". The women were fasting for 3 days, and they became sick. So much so, that they couldn't read the Torah. Thus, we read ויחל in their honor and commemoration of their sickness.